# Group claim setup in Azure Enterprise application using graph api

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Is it possible to do "Add a group claim" using graph API.

I have done like this below, but What i need is i need to create one group claim first and then add this below claim too

```
    {
      "definition": [
        "{\"ClaimsMappingPolicy\":{\"Version\":1,\"IncludeBasicClaimSet\":\"true\", \"ClaimsSchema\": [{\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"displayname\",\"SamlClaimType\": \"displayname\"}, {\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"mail\",\"SamlClaimType\": \"email\"}, {\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"groups\",\"SamlClaimType\": \"groups\"}, {\"Source\":\"user\",\"ID\":\"userprincipalname\",\"SamlClaimType\": \"username\"}]}}"
        ],
      "displayName": "Jenkins CM policy",
      "isOrganizationDefault": false
    }
```

Question: What I am trying to do?

I need to create a group claim with the string security-group and name is "groups" and need to create the above option claim too using Graph API.

Group claim:

```
Groups: name=groups value=user.groups
```

Additional attributes: New claim

```
User Name: name=username value=user.userprincipalname
Display Name: name=displayname value=user.displayname
Email: name=email value=user.mail
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello @hashimvayalar, may i know if you are using this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/claimsmappingpolicy-post-claimsmappingpolicies?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) ??

Comment: Also can you please add more details on  what are you trying to do .. are you trying to change this [setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/reference-app-manifest?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps#groupmembershipclaims-attribute) and add a optional claim

Comment: @AnsumanBal-MT Updated more details